# Как нужно задать цикл так, чтобы не выдавалась ошибка IndexError

Tags: python, list, index

В функции check задаются два параметра: param - количество элементов в списке и num - сам список. Сначала проверяем, совпадает ли количество заданных элементов в списке с тем количеством, которое было введено пользователем. Далее у меня стоит такая задача: я должен посмотреть, есть ли в списке одинаковые элементы и удалить один из них. У меня выдаётся ошибка IndexError: list index out of range в 13 строке. Помогите пожалуйста, очень нужно. Спасибо!

```
def check(param, num):
    if (param != len(num)):
        print(param)
        print(len(num))
        return False
    else:
        a = len(num)
        for i in range(a):
            for j in range(a):
                if (i == j):
                    continue
                else:
                    if (num[i] == num[j]):
                        num.pop(j)
    return num
c = 9
d = [2, 1, 3, 2, 9, 1, 2, 3, 1]

print(check(c, d))
```

Comment: Что должна вывести программа?

Comment: Я уже отредактировал программу. Она должна возвращать список, в котором нет одинаковых элементов, если предыдущее условие выполняется.

Comment: Если количество элементов в списке соответствует заявленному?

Comment: То выполняется следующая ветвь функции в которой предполагается удаление одинаковых элементов в списке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Ошибка в этом блоке:

```
a = len(num)
    for i in range(a):
        for j in range(a):
            if (i == j):
                continue
            else:
                if (num[i] == num[j]):
                    num.pop(j)
```

> Дело в том, что после `num.pop(j)`, удаляющей элементы из списка, количество элементов в списке сократиться а переменная `a` не изменится, поэтому наступит такой момент когда значение `j` или `i` в цикле, превысит количество элементов присутствующих в списке на тот момент.

#### Как мне кажется, решение может выглядеть так:

```
def check(param, num):
    if len(num) == param:
        return list(sorted(set(num), key=lambda s: num.index(s)))
    else:
        print('Заявленное количество элементов %s\n'
              'не соответвует реальному %s' % (param, len(num)))
        return False
```

#### Вариант решения через цикл (с форматированием вывода не заморачивался):

```
def check(param: int, num: list):
    if param == len(num):
        for _ in range(len(num)):
            for j in range(len(num)):
                if num.count(num[j]) > 1:
                    num.pop(j)
                    break
        print(num)
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Да, я понял что ошибка в этом блоке, я даже указал строку. Мне уже помогли, спасибо вам за ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, он мне подходит тоже)